# Is it possible to make a file response with a file from another domain in Laravel hosted on Plesk?

Tags: laravel, permissions, plesk

I have two laravel projects on the same server under two different domains. Basically an admin site and client site. Usersite is using content that is stored on admin site. It works fine until I need to present a pdf to a user that is stored on the admin site. I do that with

```
return response()->file($filePath, ['Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="'.$object->title.'.pdf','Content-Type' => 'application/pdf']);
```

Now the problem with this is that these are hosted on Plesk, meaning usersite is not authorized to access files on admin site and I get errors like

```
open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/var/www/vhosts/dominaname/httpdocs/storage/app/public/myfile.pdf) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/domainname:/tmp/:/var/www/vhosts/dominaname/httpdocs/storage/app/public/)
```

I have followed an [article](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000278993-A-website-hosted-in-Plesk-is-not-accessible-open-basedir-restriction-in-effect) explaining how to set open_basedir settings to allow this but they do not work as I'm still getting the same error.
I have also tried to achieve the same result with

```
return Storage::response($filePath);
```

But that didn't work either.

Comment: Are you using a symlinked public dir locally?

Comment: @aethergy yes, I have a symlink in usersite's public folder which points to admin site public storage